# Invalid opcode during division

Tags: solidity, integers

I have seen many posts around the division operation in Solidity e.g. [Cant' do any integer division](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/15090). Firstly, the error I am facing is different. Secondly, I am ensuring that, all numbers in division operation are set to `uint256`. So, I am not sure, what this error means and how to fix this.

This is with Ethereum testrpc.

**Solidity function**

```
function getQuotient() returns (uint256) {

    uint256 numMembers = uint256(someStruct.someArray.length);
    uint256 sampleSum = someSameplSum; //set to uint256 elsewhere
    uint256 avgNum = sampleSum / numMembers;

    return avgNum;
}
```

**Error**

```
Error: Error: VM Exception while executing eth_call: invalid opcode
    at /home/ubuntu/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/build/cli.node.js:59368:17
    at /home/ubuntu/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/build/cli.node.js:69306:5
    at /home/ubuntu/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/build/cli.node.js:11335:9
    at /home/ubuntu/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/build/cli.node.js:7895:16
    at replenish (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/build/cli.node.js:8415:25)
    at iterateeCallback (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/build/cli.node.js:8405:17)
    at /home/ubuntu/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/build/cli.node.js:8380:16
    at /home/ubuntu/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/build/cli.node.js:11332:13
    at /home/ubuntu/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/build/cli.node.js:69302:9
    at /home/ubuntu/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/build/cli.node.js:63982:7
    at Object.InvalidResponse (/Users/nsubrahm/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/errors.js:38:16)
    at /Users/nsubrahm/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/requestmanager.js:86:36
...
```

Comment: If `numMembers` is zero, the division will throw an exception. Exceptions are reported as invalid opcode.

Comment: I think, I am running into that case `numMembers=0`. Thanks for the hint!