# Solidity Language: Fractional Percentage Numbers:

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, remix

I have following function, I'm trying to put a rate which is supposed to be a fractional number e.g. 0.5, 1.5, 3.7 or similar - Everytime I attempt to do so, the rate truncates - How can I fix this? is this a remix bug?

```
 function tokenTransferTwo(address _recipient, uint256 _amount, uint256 _rate) external onlyOwner returns (bool) {
        require(_recipient != address(0));
        require(_amount <= balances[msg.sender]);

        tokensReceived[_recipient] = _amount;
          tokenBalance[_recipient] = _amount;
                  rate[_recipient] = (_rate * 10) / 100; //SafeMath don't work either
        receivedTokens[_recipient] = true;

        balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(_amount);
        balances[_recipient] = balances[_recipient].add(_amount);

        emit TokensTransferred(msg.sender, _recipient, _amount, rate[_recipient]);
        return true;
```

Comment: Check out this: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/15090/cant-do-any-integer-division/15091#15091 And this: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/52781/division-percentages-in-solidity-a-workaround/52789#52789 Hope it helps.

Comment: You may find useful Mikhail Vladimirov's Math in Solidity series, particularly [Part 1: Numbers](https://medium.com/coinmonks/math-in-solidity-part-1-numbers-384c8377f26d) and [Part 2: Overflow](https://medium.com/coinmonks/math-in-solidity-part-2-overflow-3cd7283714b4).

Answer (score 6):

Solidity does not understand assigning fractional numbers to variables. They should work correctly in calculations (something like  `3 / 2 * 6`) but you can't assign a fractional result to a variable. Documentation: http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/types.html#fixed-point-numbers

With Ether / token amounts this is typically not a problem as all amounts are expressed in the smallest indivisible unit (wei in Ether). Typically in token crowdsale contracts the rate is also some rather big numbers, like 100000.

You need to code your contracts so that you don't need to store fractional numbers anywhere. If really needed, you can multiply them for example by 100 and when used in calculations, divide again by 100.

Answer (score 1):

Solidity does not support fractional numbers natively, though there are libraries for this.  Check [ABDK Math 64.64](https://github.com/abdk-consulting/abdk-libraries-solidity/blob/master/ABDKMath64x64.md) library.  It may do `integer/integer->fraction`, `integer*fraction->integer`, as well as all basic math operations with fractions.

Comment: Caveat: the ABDK math library works with binary numbers, which has certain implications. For example, 1 is assumed to be `0x10000000000000000` (1 followed by 64 zero bits).

Answer (score 1):

i made a fraction library with some computations, please check em and let me know any inconveniences or bugs
https://github.com/pakchu/Fractions
struct [numerator,denominator]
which is [uint, uint] -> fraction