# Multiply small rational number to obtain integer piece

Tags: solidity, contract-development, private-blockchain, evm

I'm trying to make some advanced calculations in Solidity. I was able to successfully implement the algorithm on my contract, but its results are way below zero, and whenever I try to get it with Javascript, it justs rounds down to 0. Is there any way I can multiply a fraction stored in a variable by a really big number so I can get some precision here? Example:

```
uint256 x = uint256(5)/uint256(10);
```

and then:

```
x *= 100;
```

resulting in:

```
> x = 50 <
```

And here is some of the code I implemented:

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the EVM deals only with integers, 5/10 = 0. Subsequent multiplication is irrelevant.

Change the order of operations so division comes last and consider this idea for decimals of precision, if needed. [Can't do any integer division](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/15090/cant-do-any-integer-division)

Hope it helps.